# Where should assets go in a CodeIgniter project?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just starting with CodeIgniter, and I am not sure where things such as css, js, and images should go. Outside the whole system folder seems ok, but that means everything is seperate. Inside means the filepaths are longer, and I'm worried that it might mess things up. What's the best practice on this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually put separate folders at the root level, so I end up with a directory structure like this:

```
/system
/css
/js
/img
```

Seems to work for me - when you use `site_url(url)`, the URL it generates is from the root, so you can use `site_url('css/file.css')` to generate URLs to your stylesheets etc.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wanted to be able to use site_url, so this makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean you keep your system folder inside a public directory?

Comment: @Blowski Yes. I know it's not best practice but I don't think it's necessarily an issue, especially if you use .htaccess to close off access to it.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I rip the `application` directory out of the `system` directory and make it a sibling to `system`. I then create a project directory in `public_html (www)` where I move index.php and store my public assets.

Let's assume the project you're working on is called `projekt`. In the parent directory to `public_html (www)` create a directory called `CISYSTEM`, and inside that directory create a directory from the version you're using, `202`, `210` etc.

```
/CISYSTEM
    /202
    /210
    /another_CI_version
/projekt_application
    /models
    /views
    /controllers
    /private_assets
/public_html
    /projekt
        index.php
        .htaccess
        css
        img
        js
        lib
```

The beauty of this directory structure is it adds another layer of security and makes it dead-easy to upgrade/swap out your CI core. Plus, you're not supposed to make changes to the core - having a single directory where your core is stored and having all projects reference it keeps things DRY.

All this directory shuffling requires you to reroute a few things though. Luckily, CodeIgniter makes it easy -- all changes can be made in the `index.php` file.

Open `index.php` and reroute a couple things:

Change: `$system_path = 'system';`

To: `$system_path = '../../CISYSTEM/210';`

Change: `$application_folder = 'application';`

To: `$application_folder = '../../projekt_application';`

---

Also, I see a lot of people talking about using `site_url()` in the other answers. I recommend a less verbose way of using `site_url()`... you don't have to call it every time if you make use of HTML's `<base>` element:

`<base href="<?= site_url();?>">`

Just include that in your application's `<head>` and you can call your controllers directly... as in:

`<a href='controllername/functionname'>Some Action</a>`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I hate having so many directories at the root level, so I use /public and use htaccess to rewrite /scripts to /public/scripts and so on.

Comment: Could you post your mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

I find it best to keep the assets on the root level.  You can use `<?=base_url()?>` to echo the full root of the site.  In the config file, you set up the root of the website.  This statement just echoes that out.

Because of this, you can use includes like this:

```
<link href="<?=base_url()?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

anywhere in your code, and it will still get http://example.com/css/style.css.

Answer (score 1):

base_url()/css/name.css

Comment: base_url() actually includes the trailing slash so you'd want: base_url() . 'css/name.css';

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the site_url(url) helper in this way you MUST first configure Apache mod_rewrite (or equivalent) to remove the index.php segment from the URI.

Otherwise the site_url method adds index.php to the URL which will likely screw up the paths to your assets if you've got them in the base directory like above.

Here's the CodeIgniter documentation on removing index.php from the URI:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/